# Why isn't toggleClass working in this case?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have written some code and it is not working.

Can someone point out my error?  Perhaps I am having problems selecting correct element?

I have written some code and it is not working.

Can someone point out my error? Perhaps I am having problems selecting correct element?

I have written some code and it is not working.

Can someone point out my error? Perhaps I am having problems selecting correct element?

```js
function toggle(x) {
  $("#content div:nth-child(" + x + ")").toggleClass("change"); 
  $("#content div img:nth-child(" + x + ")").toggleClass("bigger"); //Not working...
}
```

```css
.bigger {
  max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
  border: 150px solid blue;
}

.posts {
  height: 210px;
  max-width: 210px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="body">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="posts" onclick="toggle(1)">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"></img>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="posts" onclick="toggle(2)">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"></img>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess I would say you are trying to target the image of the xth child div. But what you are doing is targeting the xth child image of every div. But in your html there is only one image in each div so nothing will change if x is greater than 1.

Comment: You probably wanted to do `#content div:nth-child("+x+") img` instead

Comment: What are you trying to select?

Comment: I just want to change the selected div tag's image dimensions to 400 x 400.  That is what I am trying to do.  It is putting a border around image but it is not changing the dimensions of image.

Comment: See my comment. Your answer is there.

Comment: The dimensions of the image are not changing after I click, although now a blue border is showing on images after I click.

Comment: Max-width and max-height doesn't change the dimensions of the image, only the maximum size of the image.

Comment: And your bigger class includes a border. That proves that it is working correctly now. You should change max-width and max-height to just width and height.

Comment: I changed them and image is not changing size, puzzling...

Comment: Hmm that's weird. Did you remove the max-width and max-height?

Comment: Never mind what I wrote.  I had another css that was controlling height and width, and I guess it was applying that one over my class definition.

Comment: I had this in my CSS file:  #content div img {width: 210px, height 210px}... I ended up removing it entirely and it is now working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To target specific image change

```
$("#content div img:nth-child("+x+")").toggleClass("bigger");
```

To

```
 $("#content  div:nth-child(" + x + ") img").toggleClass("bigger");
```

If you think about it...each of those `<div>` only has one image child